# MIPS Assembly Language Homework

Tags: assembly, mips

My teacher gave us a worksheet to complete that has to do with MIPS assembly language. I'm trying to figure it out. This is her first year teaching and I don't think she's quite got the hang of it yet. She has caused more confusion in the class than understanding, but perhaps it's just the subject matter.

I've been doing a lot of research but nothing I have found has a format that I can compare to her question. I believe if I can get help with just the first question I can compare that to the rest of the homework and come up with a better understanding of the way it works.

**1. Map your initials to letters of the alphabet e.g. A=1, B=2, C=3 etc. Then write a MIPS program that loads a value from memory location 0 into the register mapping to your first initial (Value A) ...**

My first initial is C=3. Can someone show me what this should look like?

- The load word Example from the book states the format should look like lw $s1,20($s2)

So in that example is 20 the memory location, or the value that they are putting into $s2? or neither?

Thank you in advance for anyone who helps, and I apologize if I haven't made any sense in asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
lw $s1,20($s2)
```

Load word at RAM address inside s2 + 20 into s1.

Comment: Well it's A[4], technically, since it's zero-based.